# Why are Google Analytics goal conversion failures showing the same page as one of the funnel steps

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a simple goal.  It's a destination goal, so basically tracking people who come to a page, and sign up for a Eval, then reach the "thank you" page.  This seems pretty standard.

The question to me is with the users that fail to convert, why is the `/evaluations` page showing in the red?  Of 41 people who came to the `/evaluations` page (the only funnel step in this goal,) 35 show as on that page, 1 exited, and 5 completed.

Why and how are 35 showing on the `/evaluations` page?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a user submits incomplete or incorrect information, the server may return the `/evaluations` page for them again so that they can correct any mistakes.  When this happens, the funnel shows them leaving the funnel on the `/evaluations` page.